# How do you write an empty while loop in Coffeescript?

Tags: coffeescript

I'm trying to translate some old code to Coffeescript. But there is no direct translation for:

```
while ( doWork() ) {}
```

"while doWork()" with nothing after it results in a syntax error.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
while doWork() then
```

Should do the trick

Comment: Or if you're willing to trade a few bytes for readability, I think `continue while doWork()` would be the clearest way to write it.

Comment: I use `(->)` as a no-op, since its the shortest one I've found, so I would do `(->) while doWork()`.

Comment: @Trevor I am amazed how your suggestion is incredibly readable (syntacticly) and surprisingly obscure (semantically). I would never understand how it works without the Aaron comment :) (But it is a really beautiful idiom and I would happily post it as an answer).

Comment: @Aaron If you're going to go for *shortest* no-op, why not `0 while doWork()`? It also has the benefit of compiling to JavaScript that's only 1 byte short of perfect efficiency. :)

Comment: or `loop break unless doWork()`

Answer (score 2):

using `then` is probably the canonical solution since it is explicitly meant for separating the condition from the (in this case empty) body.  Alternatively you can write

```
while doWork()
  ;#
```

(the `#` keeps vim syntax highlighting from flagging it as an error)

I also like the `continue while doWork()` solution, but I strongly advise against any other form of `expression while doWork()` mentioned in the comments since when this is the last statement of a function it will become a list constructor:

```
_results = [];
while (doWork()) {
  _results.push(expression);
}
return _results;
```